# jQuery UI Tabs first loaded tab is cached, alhough ajaxOptions: cache: false is specified

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, razor, jquery-ui-tabs

I have tabs where every tab is loaded using ajax. I do not want to cache (I want ajax request any time the tab is cliked). I created tabs as following:
`$('#tabs').tabs({ ajaxOptions: { cache: false}, spinner: 'Loading task...' });`

Thanks  to the above, when I click on a tab, a special variable is appended:
`http://localhost:3252/Task/Show/2?_=1327576289684`
It prevents prevents caching by making the url unique, so the request is always sent to the server.

However, when I open the page with the tabs, they are initialized and the default tab (Task 1) is loaded. In this case the variable is not appended:
`http://localhost:3252/Task/Show/1`
which consequently causes the page to load from cache.

I changed the behavior by changing the tab url to contain a per request unique number (ticks in my case):

```
@<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        @Code
            For Each task In Model.Tasks
                @<li><a href="@task.Url?_=@DateTime.Now.Ticks"><span>@task.Name (@task.Number)</span></a><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove task</span></li>                   
            Next
        End Code
    </ul>
    @*@Html.EditorFor(Function(m) (m.Tasks))*@
</div>
```

The question is: why do I have to do that? Isn't it something that you would like to solve with `ajaxOptions: { cache: false}`? Has anyone encountered this problem before and found a nice solution to it? Am I missing something or is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing the main jQuery ajax settings cache to false? It may be that you need a blanket setting as a default that covers all ajax requests. You could place this in your document ready:

```
// Force requested pages not to be cached by the browser
$.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
```

Docs for reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I tried what you said, but no luck. Even if it worked, then does the described behavior sound logic to you?

Comment: Ok...I see you've added a timestamp to your URL in the html links: `@task.Url?_=@DateTime.Now.Ticks` Can you add a timestamp to the initial URL or the GET parameters? That would most likely sort it.

Comment: The problem is solved as you can read in my original post. The problem I have is that I don't like the fact that I needed to solve it in my own way. I am also curious why `ajaxOptions: { cache: false}` does not work for the first tab loaded by default...